# Quicksort in-place for list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I got a task to sort data with quicksort in-place. The input is a list of lists (name, score1, score2).

The data should be sorted by score1 in descending order, then (if equal) by score2 in ascending order, then (if equal) by name in ascending order.

Example input:

```
5
antony 4 100
jack 6 1000
jerry 2 90
ricky 2 90
timy 4 80
```

Expected output:

```
jack
timy
antony
jerry
ricky
```

So far I have coded the quicksort in-place algorithm and tested it with some custom input, but I can't figure out how to compare values in a list of lists. Or is there any other way to do this comparison?

```
import random

def compare(l1, l2):
    if l1[1] > l2[1]:
        return True
    elif l1[1] == l2[1] and l1[2] < l2[2]:
        return True
    elif l1[2] == l2[2] and l1[1] == l2[1] and l1[0] > l1[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def quicksort(A, l=0, r=None):
    if r is None:
        r = len(A) - 1
    # end = len(array) - 1
    if l >= r:
        return
    else:
        q = random.choice(A[l:r + 1])
        i = l
        j = r
        while i <= j:
            while compare(q, A[i]):
                i += 1
            while compare(A[j], q):
                j -= 1
            if i <= j:
                A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
                i += 1
                j -= 1
                quicksort(A, l, j)
                quicksort(A, i, r)
    return A

def read_input():
    k = int(input())
    values = []
    while k > 0:
        n = input().split()
        values.append(n[0])
        values.append(n[1])
        values.append(n[2])
        k -= 1
    return values
```

Comment: You could write a function, say `compare`, that takes 2 name/score/score lists and returns which is larger; then call that function instead of doing your `<` comparison on your `while` loops.

Comment: Please spell out how *timy* is to precede *antony*.

Comment: @greybeard updated description

Comment: @ScottHunter tried to add compare func, but still not sorting right, what can it be wrong?

Comment: Without being able to *see* your compare function or how you tried to use it, who's to say?

Comment: @ScottHunter i edited my question, u can see compare func there

Comment: @greybeard: Because *timy* has a lower score2 than *anthony*?

Comment: Your result is exactly backwards; doesn't that suggest how to fix your compare function?

Comment: @ScottHunter: `result is exactly backwards` if requirement was ascending - which isn't specified explicitly. Note that I asked about [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74044942/1). (And somehow I got the notion it's not the output that's *sorted alphabetical*, but the input.)

Comment: @greybeard: When I ran the posted code on the sample input, the result I got was the reverse of the stated expected output.  (Well, sometimes `ricky` and `jerry` were swapped.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following issues in your code:

- `read_input` reads all values in a 1 dimensional list, i.e. it doesn't create a list of *triplets*
- `read_input` does not convert the scores to `int` data type, but leaves them as strings, which will have an impact on how they are compared by `compare`

  To solve these two issues, change the body of the loop in `read_input` with this:

  ```
  name, score1, score2 = input().split()
  values.append([name, int(score1), int(score2)])
  k -= 1
  ```
- `compare` returns `True` when the first argument should be ordered *after* the second argument. When you call `compare` you treat `True` as a message *not to swap*. But you pass the arguments in the order as they appear in the input, which means you should swap when you get `True`. So here the code is wrong. Fix by passing the arguments in opposite order.
- The recursive calls of `quickSort` are made at the wrong time. These calls should not be done during the loop, but *after* it.
- `quicksort` has a `return` without list and a `return A` with list. This is not consistent. As `quicksort` is *inplace* it is more pythonic to *not* return the list, so change that final `return`. The caller should take the list that it passed as argument, which will have been sorted.
- `compare` has a typo in the string comparison: it has `l1[0] > l1[0]` (the two operands are the same), which should be `l2[0] > l1[0]`

Here is your code with the above mentioned corrections:

```
def compare(l1, l2):
    if l1[1] > l2[1]:
        return True
    elif l1[1] == l2[1] and l1[2] < l2[2]:
        return True
    elif l1[2] == l2[2] and l1[1] == l2[1] and l2[0] > l1[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def quicksort(A, l=0, r=None):
    if r is None:
        r = len(A) - 1
    if l >= r:
        return
    else:
        q = random.choice(A[l:r + 1])
        i = l
        j = r
        while i <= j:
            while compare(A[i], q):  # args swapped
                i += 1
            while compare(q, A[j]):  # args swapped
                j -= 1
            if i <= j:
                A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
                i += 1
                j -= 1
        quicksort(A, l, j)  # Fixed indentation
        quicksort(A, i, r)
    return  # Don't return A

def read_input():
    k = int(input())
    values = []
    while k > 0:
        name, score1, score2 = input().split()
        # Append a triple, and convert the scores to int:
        values.append([name, int(score1), int(score2)])
        k -= 1
    return values
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i used provided code and got quite close result to an answer but the algorithm somehow not sorting names alphabetically. If the input is `5
antony 0 0
jack 0 0
jerry 0 0
ricky 0 0
timy 0 0` , output will be `[['ricky', 0, 0], ['timy', 0, 0], ['jerry', 0, 0], ['antony', 0, 0], ['jack', 0, 0]]` but should be sorted alphabetically, what can be wrong with that?

Comment: edited compare func, to sort names alphabetically by first letter

Comment: update, i have to sort alphabetically by all letters

Comment: Yes, you had a typo in the string comparison. Your update to my answer was wrong. I replaced it with the correction you need for that typo.

Comment: just one more question, will it work if the input is single elemnent array? like `1
a 0 0`

Comment: Why do you ask? Is there a problem with that case?

Comment: it was a problem with output, but figured out how to manage that, now its perfectly fine, thanks again!